# How Can I add Choices in the Django User model

Tags: django-users, python-3.9

I want to add two choices to the Django User model and also I want to inherit a form from `UserCreationForm` that are derived from `django.contrib.auth.forms`.When I used the below code I got different error.Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

forms.py

```
TYPE_CHOICES =(
("individual", "Individual"),
("company", "Company"),
)


class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','type']
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

TYPE_CHOICES =(
    ("individual", "Individual"),
    ("company", "Company"),
)

class User(AbstractUser):
    type = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES,max_length=20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use django model's `choices` for this. First create object for your choices.

```
your_choices = (
    (1, u'Active'),
    (2, u'Inactive')
)
```

Add these choices to your model class.

```
choice_field = models.IntegerField(choices=your_choices)
```

Now extend your form class.

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
        first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
        last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
        email = forms.EmailField(max_length=75)
        choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=your_choices)
    
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "email", "choice_field",)
```

Comment: Here  I have used Django User model.When I use 'choice_field = models.IntegerField(choices=your_choices)' inside 'class User(AbstractUser):' I got an error.Can you show how to write the code in the models.py file.@vivekpadia70

Comment: You can follow this tutorial https://raturi.in/blog/how-extend-django-user-model/